# Search in app using windows search(windows universal 10)

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

Is it possible in in windows universal 10 c# to use the windows search in task bar to search in your application?

edit
in W8 there was something like this

[W8 Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmDr6.png)

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want to search for in your app? If you mean something internal to your app, how than is windows supposed to know about it? I am just wondering.

Comment: in my applications will be items with a title and a description. i want to search on those.

that is the question i'm asking. is there a way t provide the search in task bar access to my application?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Windows 10 (and Cortana) just allows search Apps (title), Settings, Files and Web.